# Creating a log program to log input

Tags: java, arrays, logging

I’m trying to create a log program to log Boats for the day and I’m trying to let the user view the current log when they type in "log", but once they view the log the program starts over and the log becomes empty until they enter a new boat. Is there anyway to make it so that even if they check the log the previous logged Boats show and once they add a new boat after checking the log… it adds that boat to the previous log?

**Log class**

```
public class Log {

  //creates an array list for boats to be stored
  private ArrayList<Boat> log;


  public Log() {
    log = new ArrayList<Boat>();
  }

  //method to add boats to the list
  public void addBoat(Boat a) {
    log.add(a); 

  }

  //method to view what's on the array list or boat log
  public void viewLog() {

    // print headings
    System.out.printf("%8s%10s  %8s%10s  %8s%n", "Boat", "Position","Gas","Ice","Price");

    System.out.printf("%8s%10s  %8s%10s  %8s%n", "========","========","========","========","========");

    // for each boat in this log
    for (int i = 0; i < log.size(); i++) {
        Boat current = log.get(i);    // get next boat

        // print boat info and where it is.
        System.out.printf("%8s%10s%10s%10s   $%6s%n%n", current.getName().toUpperCase(),current.getPosition().toUpperCase(),current.getGasAmount().toUpperCase(),current.getIceAmount().toUpperCase(),current.getPrice());

    }
  }
}
```

**Main class**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class LogTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //boolean variable in order to pass control 
    //back to the top of the program
    //instance variables to pass into constructor
    boolean run = true;
    String boatName;
    String position;
    String gas;
    String ice;

    while (run) {

        //log object to store when a boat is entered 
        Log dailyLog = new Log();

        //options to add a boat to the array list
        //or to view the current array list
        //or to remove a boat from the array list (this method is not made yet)
        String boatLog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("To add a boat type 'Add'\n"
                + "To view todays log type 'Log'\n"
                + "To remove a boat type 'Remove'\n" + "Hit 'Cancel' to quit");

        //if user enters nothing then show the Error message 
        //and re-display menu screen
        while (boatLog.isEmpty()) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not entered anything. "
                    + "Try again", "ERROR!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            boatLog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("To add a boat type 'Add'\n"
                    + "To view todays log type 'Log'\n"
                    + "To remove a boat type 'Remove'\n" + "Hit 'Cancel' to quit");
        }
        //if use enters "add" then ask for the boats name 
        //where they want it to go (water or wash) 
        //if it needs gas and ice
        while (boatLog.equalsIgnoreCase("Add")) {

            //variables for boat object constructer
            boatName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Boat Id");
            position = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("If this boat is "
                    + "going to the water enter 'Water'\n" + "If this boat is"
                    + "going to the wash rack enter 'Wash'");
            gas = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is this boat getting gas?");
            ice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is this boat getting ice?");

            //boat object constructer
            Boat addBoat = new Boat(boatName, position, gas, ice);

            //methods to confirm position and how much gas & ice the boat wants 
            addBoat.position();
            addBoat.gasAmount();
            addBoat.iceAmount();

            //displays the options they choose for their boat
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    String.format("Boat: %s\nGoing to: %s\nAmount of Gas (Gallons): %s\nAmount of Ice: %s\n", addBoat.getName().toUpperCase(), addBoat.getPosition().toUpperCase(), addBoat.getGasAmount().toUpperCase(), addBoat.getIceAmount().toUpperCase()),
                    "New Boat", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            //adds boat to array list
            dailyLog.addBoat(addBoat);

            //re-displays menu screen
            boatLog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("To add a boat type 'Add'\n"
                    + "To view todays log type 'Log'\n"
                    + "To remove a boat type 'Remove'\n" + "Hit 'Cancel' to quit");

        }
        //remove method (coming soon <3)
        while (boatLog.equalsIgnoreCase("Remove")) {

        }
        //if user choose to view log then display items of the array
        if (boatLog.equalsIgnoreCase("Log")) {

            dailyLog.viewLog();

        }

        //if at all user hits cancel then whole loop stops and system exits
        if (boatLog == null) {

            run = false;

        }

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reinitializing your log in each iteration of your `while` loop.  Move this line to before the loop.

```
Log dailyLog = new Log();
```

Comment: Is there anyway to delete the previous log now? so in the output it only shows the current viewed log

Comment: @JoshuaWoohMcLendon You can use `dailyLog = new Log();` to clear the existing log and start fresh.

Comment: I'm trying to add the remove method that runs if they choose to remove a boat by typing remove in the menu dialog message. Then have it show up in the log  saying removed and then remove it from the array. so that the next time they go to see the log it shows that the boat was marked as removed only. helppppp!

Comment: @JoshuaWoohMcLendon You should make a new question.  It's hard to have that conversation in the comments section.